# Audio streaming and udp doubt

Tags: pic, audio

I'm doing a project, where I have to decode an mp3 audio stream which I receive from a web server, with a pic32 over Ethernet. My doubt is:

What if the server sends more data than the pic can handle? I mean, Can I control the amount of packets that the server send me? Because if I there is only one device connected to the web, the server will send all the mp3 song at without wait, and the pic memory will be not enough.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a proper streaming protocol like RTSP, then the server will send the packets at the correct rate.

Answer (score 0):

UDP does not provide flow control. If you need that you should use TCP traffic *OR* a higher protocols would have to implement flow control, but basic http doesn't provide flow control either. As most such data streams are either real time or TCP based, I doubt any of the higer protocols have flow control implemented. My hunch is you have to switch to TCP.

Comment: HTTP runs over TCP and therefore does have flow control.

Comment: @EJP It usually does, but not necessarily.

Comment: HTTP 'presumes a reliable transport', and that in turn in practice presumes some sort of flow control.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the server, have it send the data at the right long term average rate.  Then the PIC only needs to deal with the burstiness.  With a big enough buffer, all should work.

Inevitably though, the two clocks will be a little off.  The long term average of each should be as good as its crystal.  To be pessimistic, figure 50 ppm crystals at both ends, so design for up to 100 ppm long term mismatch.  This can be dealt with several ways.  You could simply replicate the last sample on buffer underrun and skip a sample on overrun since in theory each will be a relatively rare event.  Or you can slightly change the playback speed based on the amount of data in the buffer.  Audio purests won't like that, but is no different than wobble of tape recorders from long ago.  Below some level is all still good enough.  If this sound is voice you can get away with a lot more than if a professional musician is listening to music.

In any case, no you don't want to use TCP.  That will add so much overhead on the PIC end that you may not be able to handle the audio stream at all.  There is no need for reliable delivery here.  If there is a glitch, the output glitches, but then you want to move on and continue normally as fast as possible.  TCP is not well suited for that.